# Linuxのmoreコマンドでパターン検索後、複数画面に渡るようなテキストをコピペするには？

Tags: centos

**Linuxのmoreコマンドで、パターン検索した後**
・検索結果ページに対して、前ページ後ページへ移動するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
・検索キーワード位置から目視で確認していき、最終的には「複数画面に渡るような文字列」を画面からコピペしたいのですが…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

moreコマンドは古いコマンドなのでlessを使います．

```
less -N filename
```

で行番号付きでファイルfilenameの中を見ることができます．

```
/pattern
```

で文字列patternを検索できます．また，uキーとdキーでページをスクロールできます．
これで取り出したい範囲の始まりの行番号と終わりの行番号を確認できたら，lessは終了して，後はsedコマンドを使って取り出すことができます．
例えば始まりが42行目，終わりが1234行目なら，次のようにします．

```
sed -n 42,1234p filename > newfile
```

これでファイルnewfileに取り出したい範囲が書き込まれます．